# Trim leading 0 for length greater than x in a dataset

Tags: sql, sqlite, dataset, querying

Take this table for example

Table 1:

```
Name.  ID
David 00513
George 0523
Carmen 3216
```

In this table, I want to trim the leading 0 for David only, because his ID is greater than 4 digits. I **don't want** to trim the leading 0 for George
Whats the best way to do this in SQL?

Comment: MySQL or SQLite ? Both are different RDBMS

Comment: was looking for a solution in either. fixed post to sqlite as it might cause confusion

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is simply:

```
select right(id, 4)
```

If you are concerned about ids longer than 4 character but with non-zero initial characters:

```
select (case when length(id) > 4 
             then replace(ltrim(replace(id, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
             else id
        end)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not concerned with initial non-zeros getting chopped, then

```
select substr(ID,-4);
```

should work.  If there is possibility of having more than 4 digits with a non-zero initial, then use

```
 select printf('%04d', ID);
```

(Assuming that all characters in ID are digits)